# Ubuntu 20.04 Archive Manager doesn't properly handle rar

Tags: 20.04, archive

I installed `rar` and compressed the sublime text folder (located in home/myUser/.config/sublime-text-3) into test.rar.

The contents of that folder is:

```
Backup
Installed Packages
Lib
Local
Log
Packages
```

Why if I open test.rar with the default archive manager it shows only these two directories??

```
Installed Packages
Packages
```

[image]

If I extract it, there are all directories and files.

Thanks